# Make Caption of Image longer than Image in Subfloat

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats

I have little icons (48x48) and I want to display them using subfloat. To prevent that images from being pixelated I set the width to 1cm. But now the caption has also a length of 1cm and looks terrible. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Logo]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Bilder/icons/logo.png}}
    \hspace{1pt}               
    \caption{Graphiken der Anwendung}
    \label{fig:icons}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make the caption longer than the 1cm image?

Comment: It would be good if you could turn the code sample into a full, compilable document (i.e. starting from `\documentclass`). That will make it easier for people to try out the code.

Comment: Why are you using `\hspace{1pt}`?

Comment: After a short look in the `subfig` manual (I assume you are using this package), I found a reference to: `\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=<some length>}`. Give it a try. Another possibility for short captions would be to use `\mbox{Logo}` to avoid a line break. However, this only allows for single line sub-captions and might cause other issues.

Comment: changed the code, \hspace is for the next row of images, I'll try the \mbox

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just increase the official width of the subfloat by putting the image in a larger but invisible box:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Logo]{\makebox[5cm][c]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Bilder/icons/logo.png}}}
    \caption{Graphiken der Anwendung}
    \label{fig:icons}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It's possible also to say `\makebox[1.2\width]{...}` that will enlarge the box by the 20%.

Comment: Or `\makebox[\dimexpr\width+2cm\relax]{...}` to increase the width by e.g. 2cm.

Comment: Beautiful solution. Working perfectly with `\makebox[0.45\textwidth][c]{...}` .

Comment: @FisNaN: Nowadays you could also use the `adjustbox` package for this. `\adjustimage{width=1cm, center=0.45\textwidth}{filename.png}` should do it.